# excel gantt chart planned vs actual

Tags: excel, charts, gantt-chart

I saw this site on how to compare planned Vs actual Gantt Charts.

I made a Gantt Chart but I just don't know to do what this guy did.
its like there are two gantt charts in one...but how?!

any thoughts?

here is the link:
https://www.vertex42.com/blog/help/gantt-chart-help/actual-dates-vs-planned-dates-in-a-gantt-chart.html

THANK YOU!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure dates are formatted as dates. Create a Stacked Bar chart, with two series, Original Start as one, and `OriginalEnd - OriginalStart` as the second.

Unformatted as dates would give you data like the following

```
OriginalStart      OriginalEnd      Difference
42473              42746           273
42475              42475           1
```

And so on. What you are actually going to be plotting is the Original Start with the difference stacked on top, then simply format the Original Start to have no fill or border.

[image]

Using the Original Start and Duration as the series, the data would look like the following when plotted on a graph:

[image]

To then create a 'second' gannt graph to over lap, create two more series and plot them on a secondary axis. Playing around with custom patterns and transparency allows you to create effects as the example you gave has.

[image]

Comment: I just found this today after spending quite a bit of time trying to do the same thing. @TimWilkinson point of clarification: Is this a second, separate chart overlaid on the first or additional info on the first one?

Comment: @PC_Goldman its all part of the same chart, the second data set is plotted on a different axis

Comment: This helped me to add the second axis: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-secondary-axis-to-a-chart-025f91b8-d70a-4d4c-b645-1431ec1c8c97